# How to clear cached JavaScript files from other domain?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am adding a facebook send button to my website, for users to invite their friends. When user click a tool image a dialog with the send button will show. **However if the dialog is close and open again, the send button dispappears.** The code to show the dialog is 
[image: my code to activate the dialog]
The blocked lines show will display the button. It is a  tag actually.
Before I call the button, the situation of the website is like this [image: this]. And after I do it, the situation is like this [image: this]. There are extra js files from four domains. I seriously doubt that they are the very reason why the button don't show..
Is there anyone know how to clear those cash files?

Comment: Those are fb API's js files, they won't be interfering with your functionality. they are just cached for future usage. Your issue seems to be elsewhere, do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vkuh7ga1/2/ The FaceBook plugin seems that needs a certain domain to rely so it does not appear...

Comment: jsfiddle.net/vkuh7ga1/4/

Comment: If you are using jsfiddle , and testing out facebookapi, make sure to set domain in your app settings to "http://fiddle.jshell.net "

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Leonado/vkuh7ga1/7/  I've tried that. But there seems to be a sandbox in jsfiddle which stop facebook from changing domain. It can be found in console.